# Get the column index value of gridview?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

I am using html grid.I want to get the index values of columns that has class named **selected** . To understand it better i will give the html grid format

```
<table style="width:600px;height:200px" id="gdTable" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span id="lblFinance">Finance</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="lblRow1">r1c1</span>
            </td> 

        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>
                <span id="Label1">Finance1</span>
            </td>
            <td **class="selected"**>
                <span id="Label2">r2c1</span>
            </td>                
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td **class="selected"**>
                <span id="Label7">Finance2</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="Label8">r3c1</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

The result i wanted is 2(index of the col in second row)+1(index of col in third row)=3

The jquery i have attempted is given below.I have tried to alert the column index but not getting the desired result.

```
        function getCellValue() {
            $("#gdTable tr").each(function () {                    
                if($(this).children().hasClass("selected")){
                    var selCOL = $(this).children().hasClass("selected");
                    alert($(this).index(selCOL));
                }


            })
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
getCellValue();
function getCellValue() {
    $("#gdTable tr td.selected").each(function () {        
        alert($(this).index());
    });    
}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/2nPnT/1)

Comment: beautiful mate..thank you very much..I didnot want the index of the parent(tr) i want the index of td only and so i removed the parent from the syntax and i got the answer..